# CoocaPod: Value of type '.....' has no member '....' but should have

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I'm using [this cocoapod](https://github.com/Orderella/PopupDialog) for a little popup view to reset all stored UserDefaults. Therefor I want the "Yes" and "No" Button of the Popup horizontally aligned (default is vertical). This is my code:

```
resetBtn.touchUpInside{ [self] in
        let dialogAppearance = PopupDialogDefaultView.appearance()
        let buttonAppearance = DefaultButton.appearance()
        let title = "Do you really want to reset this game?"
        let popup = PopupDialog(title: title)
        let yesBtn = DefaultButton(title: "Yes", height: 60) {
            self.click()
            defaults.removePersistentDomain(forName: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!)
            defaults.synchronize()
        }
        let noBtn = DefaultButton(title: "No", height: 60) {
            self.click()
        }
        popup.addButton(yesBtn)
        popup.addButton(noBtn)
        dialogAppearance.messageFont = UIFont(name: "Nunito-Black", size: 18)!
        dialogAppearance.messageTextAlignment = .natural
        dialogAppearance.titleFont = UIFont(name: "Nunito-Black", size: 22)!
        buttonAppearance.titleFont = UIFont(name: "Nunito-Black", size: 22)!
        let vc = popup.viewController as! PopupDialogDefaultViewController //!!! 
        vc.buttonAlignment = .horizontal /// Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'horizontal', Value of type 'PopupDialogDefaultViewController' has no member 'buttonAlignment'
        self.present(popup, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

As you can see [right here](https://github.com/Orderella/PopupDialog#default-dialog-properties), the Creator put the buttons horizontally with this:

```
    let vc = popup.viewController as! PopupDialogDefaultViewController
    vc.buttonAlignment = .horizontal
```

But when I do exactly this, the compiles says "*Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'horizontal'", "Value of type 'PopupDialogDefaultViewController' has no member 'buttonAlignment'*"... as marked in my code.

What should I do?

Comment: What's `PopupDialogDefaultViewController`? Does it have a property named `buttonAlignment`?

Comment: @Larme Its a final public class by the Cocoapod and I has no property named buttonAlignment. But PopupDialog has

Comment: But as you can see in the last hyperlink, the pod description said it like I did

Comment: I see. I guess: `vc.view.buttonAlignment` might work, might need (vc.view as! PopDialog).buttonliignment`

Comment: Then it sais "Cast from 'UIView?' to unrelated type 'PopupDialog' always fails". As the view is not the popupview.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

Just directly write
`let popup = PopupDialog(title: title, message: message, buttonAlignment: .horizontal)`.